# QR-Code- add text below the QR code

Tags: php, image, qr-code, laravel-5.3

I'm currently providing a QR-Code for a Product in an e-commerce shop I'm building. I'm using this code:

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64, <?php echo base64_encode( QrCode::format( 'png' )->size( 500 )->encoding( 'UTF-8' )->errorCorrection( 'H' )->generate( '‌https://localhost/product/' . $product->id ) ); ?> "
    download=<?= $product->name . "_QRCode" ;?>>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, <?php echo base64_encode( QrCode::format( 'png' )->margin( 1 )->size( 50 )->encoding( 'UTF-8' )->errorCorrection( 'H' )->generate( '‌https://localhost/product/' . $product->id ) ); ?>">
</a>
```

I have an image with the qr-code and the image is clickable, downloading the qr-code image.

Is it possible to add some text under the downloaded qr-code? The text would identify the product for the qr-code, so it was visible just by looking at the code. (An example is something like [this QR code](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161202/uotorir3.png))

Comment: PHP supports editing images.  So, create the image, then use PHP to write text on the image.  Here's one of many examples of how to do so: http://www.phpforkids.com/php/php-gd-library-adding-text-writing.php

Comment: @cale_b 2 things: 1st: I already tried to do it with this method (on another problem), but somehow I had a problem with the font, no matter where I put my `arial.ttf` and how I included it, it wasn't working somehow... also 2ndly: Can I also add a white bar under the qr-code to write the text on it? Because tha's what I would need to do..

Comment: Understood (problem with font) and yes (add white space).  Now, what we need is to see the code in which you attempt to do that (white space, and your font)

Comment: @cale_b yeah but i have no idea how to do it, thats the problem... how can i add a white space and how can i add the text in exactly in that white field... About my font problem: I used exactly the same code as the example you provided...